# how remove /xa0 from pandas dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file. I read and made a dictionary with its columns. but in dictionary I have a lot of `/xa0` how I can remove them?

```
data=pd.read_csv('A.csv')
data.dropna(inplace=True)
Title = data['FIRST'].str.lower()
Abbr = data['1ST'].str.lower()
JobAbbreviation=dict(zip(Abbr, Title))
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
data = data.replace(u'\xa0', u'')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `regex=True` for substrings replacement:

```
data = data.replace(u'\xa0', u'', regex=True)
```